# Ignore warning when creating excel from Memory Stream in C# MVC

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc

I am creating excel file by convert .cshtml MVC Razor page into bytes and then converting it into Memory stream to create excel, but when opening that excel file I am getting a warning message, I want to ignore it or you can say remove it. How can I do that ( don't want to use External library like NPOI or EPPlus)

Here is my C# Code

```
          var html = FakeController.RenderViewToString2(ControllerContext, "~/Views/Report/DistirbuterPriceListExcel.cshtml", distributerListModel, true);
        var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(html);


        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);


        var root = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/ReportPDFFiles/");
        var pathtosave = "../../Uploads/ReportPDFFiles/";

        var CompURL = "";
        var FileName = "";

        var pdfname = String.Format("{0}.xls", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        var pdfCompleteName = "Distributer-List.xls";

        var path = Path.Combine(root, pdfname);
        var path2 = Path.Combine(root, pdfCompleteName);
        path = Path.GetFullPath(path);
        path2 = Path.GetFullPath(path2);


        var fileStream2 = new FileStream(path2, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        fileStream2.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        fileStream2.Close();        
        CompURL = pathtosave + pdfCompleteName;
        FileName = pdfCompleteName;

        return Json(new { CompURL, FileName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Where distributerListModel= Model passed to view, I want to return url in JSON response.

I can create excel file, but it is opening and showing results, but showing warning error "the file you are trying to open is in different format", here is the image
[image]

I want to ignore or remove the above error, how can I do that?
As the HTML layout of table is quite complicated I don't want to use EPPlus and directly want to convert html/css code into excel.

Comment: Whats wrong with using an external library ?

Comment: That is because you are not creating an excel file, but a html file with an xlsx extension. You should really use EPPlus or NPOI. If not you will have to live with the error.

Comment: @level_zebra html layout contains lots of cascading tables, so it is difficult. So just thinking if there is any way to create Excel using Memory Stream or bytearray got from HTML.

Comment: @VDWWD is there any way to convert this byte array or memory stream to excel using EPPlus or NPOI?

Comment: It will be more difficult NOT using an external library. As already mentioned your sticking random data in a file changing the extension to xls and expecting it to work because it has an xls extention.

Comment: You cannot convert the html to an excel, but you can create an excel in memorystream from the source data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002573/send-excel-email-attachment-c-sharp