# export gridview to excel using Response object

Tags: c#, asp.net

On pressing Button1, the contents of gridview1 should be exported to excel. Whereas I encounter the following error:

> System.Web.HttpException: 'Control 'GridView1' of type 'GridView' must
>   be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.'

and when I completely removed the content of the override `VerifyRenderingInServerForm()` method as shown in one of the youtube videos, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'RegisterForEventValidation can only
>   be called during Render();'

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=student.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
        StringWriter strw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmltw = new HtmlTextWriter(strw);
        GridView1.RenderControl(htmltw);

        Response.Write(strw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
         base.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control);
    }
```

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47293207/5836671) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002573/send-excel-email-attachment-c-sharp). All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to disable event validation in the page properties
      <%@ Page ............  EnableEventValidation="false" %>