# Export GridView to excel without HiddenRows

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I have this void to export a GridView rows to Excel and it works fine:

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.Charset = "";

        string fileName = "ConsultaSerialesFinishGoods_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + ".xls";
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
        
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].BackColor = Color.Blue;
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.Blue;
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Blue;
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[3].BackColor = Color.Blue;
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[4].BackColor = Color.Blue;
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[5].BackColor = Color.Blue;
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[6].BackColor = Color.Blue;
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[7].BackColor = Color.Blue;
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[8].BackColor = Color.Blue;
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[9].BackColor = Color.Blue;
        GridView1.HeaderRow.ForeColor = Color.White;

        GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.Reset();
        GridView1.RowStyle.Reset();

        GridView1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        GridView1.GridLines = GridLines.Both; //Si queremos que el excel tenga lineas
        GridView1.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
        Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Also I have this other JS function to hide rows from the GridView1 using a Textbox:

```
function Search_Gridview(strKey) {
                var strData = strKey.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
                var tblData = document.getElementById("<%=GridView1.ClientID %>");
                var rowData;
                for (var i = 1; i < tblData.rows.length; i++) {
                    rowData = tblData.rows[i].innerHTML;
                    var styleDisplay = 'none';
                    for (var j = 0; j < strData.length; j++) {
                        if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(strData[j]) >= 0)
                            styleDisplay = '';
                        else {
                            styleDisplay = 'none';
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    tblData.rows[i].style.display = styleDisplay;
                }
            }
```

I want to avoid export the hidden rows (when they are hidden using the textbox with the JS), because the Button2 is exporting all the Rows of the GridView even the hidden rows.
Do you know how can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47293207/5836671) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002573/send-excel-email-attachment-c-sharp). All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Comment: I'm seeing the Example you mentioned and I see the "public void ExportToExcel". Can you tell me in which part of the void you set to avoid to export hidden rows and just export the visible rows?

Comment: You have to filter those rows out before you build the excel. Then that would also work for your currrent method of exporting.