# ASP.NET WebForms - render control to a file returned to user

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am new for web form in the code I try to export grid view data to excel but code execute correctly no error but excel not downloaded

Grid view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GradingFinalData" runat="server" class="table table-success table-bordered" GridLines="Both"  Width="100%" AllowSorting="True"  EmptyDataText="No Data Found" PageSize="11" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowEditing="GradingFinalData_RowEditing">
                                                                    <AlternatingRowStyle />
                                                                    <RowStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="10pt" />
                                                                    <Columns>
                                                                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BatchNo" SortExpression="BatchNo" ItemStyle-Height="50px">
                                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lTestingType" ItemStyle-ForeColor="#ff0000" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("batchNo") %>' />
                                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#3699FF" BorderWidth="1px" />
                                                                            <ItemStyle BorderColor="#3699FF" BorderWidth="1px" />
                                                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Grade" SortExpression="Grade">
                                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lTestingType" ItemStyle-ForeColor="#ff0000" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("grade") %>' />
                                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#3699FF" BorderWidth="1px" />
                                                                            <ItemStyle BorderColor="#3699FF" BorderWidth="1px" />
                                                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Type" SortExpression="Product Type">
                                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lLabName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("productType") %>' />
                                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#3699FF" BorderWidth="1px" />
                                                                            <ItemStyle BorderColor="#3699FF" BorderWidth="1px" />
                                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                                                                                
                                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HeadLessWeight" SortExpression="HeadLessWeight">
                                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lUserType" ForeColor="#006666" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sampleHeadlessWeight") %>' />
                                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#3699FF" BorderWidth="1px" />
                                                                            <ItemStyle BorderColor="#3699FF" BorderWidth="1px" />
                                                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GradewiseYeild%" SortExpression="Gradewiseyeild">
                                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lUserType" ForeColor="#006666" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("YieldPercentage") %>' />
                                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#3699FF" BorderWidth="1px" />
                                                                            <ItemStyle BorderColor="#3699FF" BorderWidth="1px" />
                                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Button event:

```
<div class="form-control-sm">
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnexpexcel" runat="server" Text="ExportToExcel"  OnClick="btnexpexcel_Click" />
                                            </div>
```

CS Code:

```
 public void exporttoexcel()
        {
            try
            {
               
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=EquipmentQuery.xls");
                Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                GradingFinalData.RenderControl(hw);
                Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation, ugh.

Comment: `throw ex;` <-- **do not do this**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2200

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47293207/5836671) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002573/send-excel-email-attachment-c-sharp). All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.